# Slow startup of second activity

Tags: android

What should I look when my settings `Activity` is starting up really slow? Sometimes I get `ANR keyDispatch error` if it takes to long.

Should also say that I am using `PreferenceActivity`. The absolute first time I go into settings the delay time is really slow (about 5-10 seconds), but otherwise it goes super smooth. This does appear when I'm reinstalling the application and start the settings for another first time (so it's a first time thing).

Some code in my settings `PreferenceActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    pref = getPreferenceManager();    

    pref.setSharedPreferencesName(LiveWallpaper.PREFERENCES);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.live);
    pref.getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    pref.findPreference("Username").setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {          
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                                          // Stuff...
                return true;                
            }
        }
    );
// And so on...
```

Basically, I want to find out where this error is located, the question is how? Can I see in LogCat WHAT it is that's causing the delay?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: I've encountered the same problem,
I think the problem is with the style you gave to your activity in the manifest.xml file.
Please post that file, if you chose a special theme, it could take some to completely load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the [TraceView](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) to measure exactly what is taking so long? This will guide you in the right direction. It's very easy to use from within Eclipse. In the DDMS view there is a button to start using TraceView.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see delays in Logcat as far as you don't Log them yourself. 
in example:

```
long start; 
long stop;

start = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
pref = getPreferenceManager(); 
stop = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
Log.d("Manager: ", "Time" + (stop - start));

start = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
pref.setSharedPreferencesName(LiveWallpaper.PREFERENCES);
stop = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
Log.d("SetSharedPrefs: ", "Time" + (stop - start));
```

Comment: Actually, logcat tell us how long it takes. Eg:
344-384/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed pck.example.MyActivity: +1s982ms